# Como hacer una paginación dentro de un modal?

Tags: html, bootstrap, modal

Encontré un código para hacer paginar un modal, el punto es que no me realiza nada al darle clic al botón , la pagina donde encontré el código es la siguiente: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/extended/modal-pagination/ pero no se que me esta faltando para que funcione ya que quiero implementar la paginación pero en un carrusel con un tope de imágenes y se vaya paginando en cada uno. Espero me puedan orientar de antemano gracias.

El boostrap que ocupo es el 3.3.7.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head> 
  <meta charset="utf-8"> 
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
  <title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Button Methods</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  
 </head> 
 <body> 
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-mdb-toggle="modal" data-mdb-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal top fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true" data-mdb-backdrop="true" data-mdb-keyboard="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog  ">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal pagination example</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-mdb-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="tab-content" id="ex1-content">
          <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="ex1-pills-1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ex1-tab-1">
            <h5 class="my-3">Page 1</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Aspernatur ratione minima suscipit! Ab
              quam distinctio tempora ad eveniet corporis repellendus?</p>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="ex1-pills-2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ex1-tab-2">
            <h5 class="my-3">Page 2</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut accusantium maiores, distinctio ut,
              quasi sapiente unde, dolore vitae quas officia corrupti maxime fugit. Omnis, nemo?</p>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="ex1-pills-3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ex1-tab-3">
            <h5 class="my-3">Page 3</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur provident numquam autem
              dolor quibusdam voluptates.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <!-- Pills navs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="ex1" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="ex1-tab-1" data-mdb-toggle="pill" href="#ex1-pills-1" role="tab"
              aria-controls="ex1-pills-1" aria-selected="true">1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <a class="nav-link" id="ex1-tab-2" data-mdb-toggle="pill" href="#ex1-pills-2" role="tab"
              aria-controls="ex1-pills-2" aria-selected="false">2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <a class="nav-link" id="ex1-tab-3" data-mdb-toggle="pill" href="#ex1-pills-3" role="tab"
              aria-controls="ex1-pills-3" aria-selected="false">3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- Pills navs -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: primero eso no es un paginadot, es un nav tab,segundo el ejemplo es para boostrap 5, deves buscar algo que se adecue a tu version

Comment: y entonces si se puede hacer paginación dentro de un modal , porque no encuentro nada similar con esa version?